# Jupyter does not show the list of available method properties for an api

Tags: python, jupyter

When I type an variable (object) name then a dot and tab key, the list of available method properties for this object(api) is supposed to show up.

[image]

this feature works well before and is not working now.

I am sure the libraries have been imported. neither restarting system nor restarting jupyter fix this.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are calling autocomplete and import at the same cell. If yes, the libraries are not being imported yet. Try to import libraries before using the **Tab** option.